# how to remove a default menu in blender using python?

Tags: python, customization

I'd like to remove some toolbar from the blender interface to simplify that for a potential customer, but I'm not able to do that using python. 
I know that it can be set up as default saving all the settings in a startup.blender file, but it doesn't work in every PC. 
For example, how to do the "Ctrl+space" over the "Layout" view with python?

My aim is illustrated in the following picture:

[image: Aim]

Comment: Are you looking for this: bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(use_hide_panels=True). [Going to this link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html?) will help you in that case.

Comment: Thank you! But this command is not working in my code, I don't understand why.
Moreover, it could be better if there is a solution to completely remove some of the pannel and not only hide them.

Comment: Check out these links: [removing panels](https://blenderartists.org/t/remove-or-hide-panels-from-add-on/529651/2) and [python api for panels](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! 
With bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(use_hide_panels=True all the pannels are hyde permanently and I'm not able to show some of them. 
Meanwhile with bpy.utils.unregister_class(bpy_types.bpy_types.*** it is possible to remove some buttons, but it's not allowed to cycle through "bpy_types.bpy_types.*" and writing a line for each button of each panel that I would like to remove is really a lot. 
Any idea?